# What is the way to show the following derivative problem?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f$ is function twice differentiable with $|f''(x)|<1, x\in [0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)$, then $|f'(x)|<1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

I have tried with Rolle's theorem, but fail

Comment: What if $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}+1000x$? Then $|f''| = \frac{1}{2} < 1$, but $f' = \frac{x}{2}+1000 \geq 1000$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Or just take $f(x) = x.$

Comment: You must be missing some additional condition on $f.$  If $f$ satisfies the conditions and $g(x)=f(x)+kx$ with any constant $k,$ then g satisfies the conditions also. But $g'(0)=f'(0)+k$ can be anything.

Comment: Sorry I have missed the condition $f(0)=f(1)$. I have updated my problem

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For some $c\in[0,1]$, $f'(c)=0$ (can you see why?).  Now apply the mean value theorem to $f'$ to bound $f'(x)$ for any other $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @EW, do you mean Lagrange mean value theorem?

Comment: Can you tell me which mean value theorem I have to apply

Comment: @MdKutubuddinSardar Google "the mean value theorem"